# MS Access VBA - how to determine if a control has a specific property

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink, properties, vba, controls

I am trying to check if a control on a form is a hyperlink using:

```
If (Len(ctl.HyperlinkAddress) < 0) Then
```

... however an error is being thrown by some controls that do not contain this property.

How can I test to see if this property exists before checking the length?

Is there a better approach to test for a hyperlink?

Thanks in advance

Lee

Answer (score 3):

http://allenbrowne.com/AppPrintMgtCode.html#HasProperty

```vb
Public Function HasProperty(obj As Object, strPropName As String) As Boolean
    'Purpose: Return true if the object has the property.
    Dim varDummy As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    varDummy = obj.Properties(strPropName)
    HasProperty = (Err.Number = 0)
End Function
```

Basically this just handles the error if the property doesn't exist.

So in your case, you could simply ignore all errors:

```vb
For Each ctl in Me.Controls
    ' Init for error case
    isHyperlink = False
    On Error Resume Next
    isHyperlink = (Len(ctl.HyperlinkAddress) > 0)
    On Error Goto ErrHandler

    If isHyperlink Then
        ' ...
    End If
Next ctl
```

Comment: The `For Each` won't tell you it's a hyperlink if Len(ctl.HyperlinkAddress) equals 0.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use error trapping, you can use `TypeOf` to test if the control has an interface that supports `.HyperlinkAddress`.

Using the object browser, you can find that the `Access.CommandButton`, `Access.Image`, `Access.Label` and `Access.NavigationButton` interface support this property.

You might want to split this condition, but in one line, it would be:

```
If TypeOf ctl Is Access.CommandButton Or TypeOf ctl Is Access.Image Or TypeOf ctl Is Access.Label Or TypeOf ctl Is Access.NavigationButton Then
    If Len(ctl.HyperlinkAddress) > 0 Then

    End If
End If
```

You can, of course, omit `Access.` here. But I tend to keep it to differentiate between MSForms controls.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that will run on a button click and check a specific control, in this case, a `Link` (which is actually a `Label` with a `Hyperlink Address` property).

```
Private Sub cmdCheckForHyperlink_Click()

    Dim prp As Property

    On Error GoTo Props_Err

    For Each prp In Me.lblHyperlink.Properties
        'Debug.Print vbTab & prp.Name & " = " & prp.Value
        If prp.Name = "HyperlinkAddress" Then
            MsgBox "It's a hyperlink."
        End If
    Next prp

Props_Exit:
    Set prp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Props_Err:
    If Err = 2187 Then
        'Property is only available at design time.
        Resume Next
    Else
        'An Error Occurred.
        Resume Next
    End If

End Sub
```

**Edit**: Note, I haven't checked to see if any other controls have a hyperlink address property, *presumably* not.

**Edit 2**: There are good approaches in the given answers but be aware that checking the length will not tell you anything if the length is zero. A good approach would probably be a combination of checking all controls that have a hyperlink property (see Erik's answer) and looping the properties to double-check the property exists, and if you need a property-value.

Answer (score 0):

Just using error catching is kind off brute force. It is more polite to loop the properties:

```
Public Function IsProperty( _
  ByVal obj As Object, _
  ByVal strName As String) _
  As Boolean

  Dim prp       As Property
  Dim booFound  As Boolean

  For Each prp In obj.Properties
    If StrComp(prp.Name, strName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
      ' Property exists.
      booFound = True
      Exit For
    End If
  Next

  IsProperty = booFound

End Function
```

Comment: I tend to value efficiency over politeness in this case. :) Looping the whole properties collection is meh. It's one of the issues with all collections - from [CPearson](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/CollectionsAndDictionaries.htm): *In a rather poor object design, the Key of an item in a Collection is write-only. [...] you cannot retrieve the Key associated with an Item nor can you determine (directly) whether a key exists in a Collection.*

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do anything in VBA but looking at the answers given, Andre's answer seems to be the most efficient to me and is also the way I deal with this type of issue

For Each ctl in Me.Controls

```
' Init for error case

isHyperlink = False

On Error Resume Next

isHyperlink = (Len(ctl.HyperlinkAddress) > 0)

On Error Goto ErrHandler

If isHyperlink Then
    ' ...
End If
```

Next ctl

Setting the default of false and turning off error checking for the single command means you are doing one check only for the control, if it fails then the false is already set otherwise it will make it true for the next block of code. Be sure to turn error checking back on.

Cycling through all the properties as Gustav suggested will work but there are so many properties to cycle through therefore so many checks = longer time to execute, by the time you multiply this by all the controls on the form will prove a big time waster, especially if there are a lot of controls.